# Devexpress RichEditControl Find function - regex throwing error

Tags: wpf-controls, devexpress, richedit-control

We are using devexpress RichEditControl in one of our windows applications. For searching any text in that control user has to press Ctrl + F and a small find text box comes hanging. When I type normal words and search everything works fine.

However, when I choose the Regular Expression mode and type "*" in the textbox to search. It gives me a huge error message.

This error and message is coming from devexpress DLLs and this I am not able to catch it or show an invalid Regex message.

Please advice if Devexpress has a way for the richeditcontrol to either allow the dev to write the regex search function or catch the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have followed instructions from [this](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7982) article and entered a valid regular expression.

If the issue is still persists, contact the [DX Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).